# Android how to draw on a canvas without a view

Tags: android, canvas

I am making an application that makes use of canvases and the images are saved on the server and seen by other users.

however the canvas-containing-view's size is dependent on the devices and therefore images made in smaller devices are blurry when seen in larger ones.

So my question is, Can I make a canvas that does not depend on a view? this way I can make a large image at background and can save the HQ image on the server.

If I cannot, please tell me a solution for such problem....

//The image-creating user can check what he draws by imageViews, so there is no need for the canvas to be visible or interactive.

//I am not able to create the images on server side....

Comment: Of course, you can do it as wrote below. But you cannot show it without some view. Only if you use native activity where it uses OpenGL viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Canvas` that draws on a `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

See [Canvas and Drawables API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).